# Not to send and specify a value of a field for a model

Tags: scala, playframework, anorm

I have a class being used in a Play app as a model:

```
case Class1(
  id: Pk[UUID] = NotAssigned,
  addedAt: DateTime = null
)

object Class1 {
  //....
}
```

The field `added_at` has a default value in db of `now()` and it can't be `NULL` in db. But nonetheless, when I want to create an instance of Class1, I have to specify it even though I don't want to send it db because it will be set to be `now()` in db:

```
Class1(addedAt = DateTime.now())
```

Using `null` as a default value seems like not a sensible idea, using `Option[DateTime] = None` doesn't make sense because it can't be null in db.
What do I do about it: I want it to exist in `Class1` because it exists in db, but at the same time I don't want to specify it because it's not needed?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you just created an object of this class and haven't sent it to the database yet. What would the result of `(new Class1).addedAt` be? You need the notion of not being assigned, same as for `id`. Since it isn't a primary key, the normal way to express it *is* `Option`. If you can ensure you always work with objects which are already sent to the database outside of your DB access layer, then keep `Option[DateTime]` in your DAL, but don't use it directly in the parts of program which don't need to deal with it being unassigned:

```
case class Class1DAL(..., addedAt: Option[DateTime])

// must ensure it is never seen with x not sent to DB
class Class1(x: Class1DAL) {
  def id = x.id

  def addedAt: DateTime = 
    x.addedAt.getOrElse(throw new IllegalStateException("Class1.addedAt unassigned, which should be impossible")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialised vs. not-initialised is definitely one valid understanding of an `Option` value, and doesn't force you to infer *where* the thing was initialised.

In this case, if you want to avoid misunderstanding, it would be enough to simply rename the value to `addedToDb` - or use an equivalent doc comment if renaming isn't an option.

I don't think anyone would have a problem with `addedToDb` being `None` for an object that hasn't yet been added to the DB!

Also... Don't use `null`, it's evil

Comment: But don't you forgot about parsing a value from db to my model? In db it's called "addedAt" and it doesn't have a type of Option[DateTime] because it's always present (it can't be null in db). We use Option only if a value in db is nullable.